# How UriTemplate variables map to WCF Web Methods

Tags: wcf

Lets say I have this method in my WCF Service:

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "users/{username}/bookmarks/{id}?format=json")]
[OperationContract]
Bookmark GetBookmarkAsJson(string username, string id)
{
    HandleGetBookmark(username, id);
}
```

How is WCF wiring up the {username} to the username param?  does it just do its magic and wire up and send the value for {username} to the string username and is it based on param to {username} match?

Answer (score 0):

It matches the query string name with parameter name in operation. Both should match.